# Converting space delimited text file to CSV VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, text, space, delimited

I have a hundreds of space delimited text files that I would like to convert in VB.NET to CSV-files according to RFC 4180. The files have variying length but can contain upp to 200000 rows and have varying ammount of columns (up to 30) separated by a number of "spaces" that also varies between one and 20. The files contains some information that I would like to remove, for example the first column and I would also like to change the content of the second column into a valid Javascript time stamp. This is an exemple of the first rows of one of the files (note that most of the spaces are not shown).

#      time         order        boil_q_1     boil_q_2     chil_q1      chil_q2      loccool      locheat      qdomwat
  0.000000000       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31529E-03   132.39       9799.3       0.0000
 8.0000000000E-02   1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31528E-03   132.11       9917.1       0.0000
 0.1600000000       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31527E-03   131.98       10047.       0.0000
 0.2705515735       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31527E-03   131.97       10152.       0.0000
 0.2705515763       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31526E-03   131.97       10152.       0.0000
 0.3345515763       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31525E-03   131.97       10184.       0.0000
 0.3985515763       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31524E-03   131.98       10192.       0.0000
 0.5265515763       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31524E-03   131.98       10178.       0.0000
 0.7825515763       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31523E-03   131.99       10164.       0.0000
 0.7825515791       1.0000      4.18700E-09   0.0000      4.18700E-11  1.31522E-03   131.99       10164.       0.0000

Any suggenstions would be wellcome.

Sincerely
Max

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you show us your current attempt at handling this so we can know what to help with?

Comment: I thought of reading line by line and splitting the columns by  using Dim split As String() = Text.Split(" ")  
Dim s As String  
For Each s In split  
 If s.Trim() <> "" Then
  Console.WriteLine(s)
 End If
Next s but there must be way better methods.

Comment: That's probably the easiest way to do it. You'll have to output commas and wrap field values in double quotes as you write the CSV.

Comment: Since you don't know how many spaces there would be, I'd say your best bet would be using `Regex.Replace` using the regex of `\s*` with your new delimitter - `,` for csv.

Comment: Sounds great, never heard of Regex.Replace

Comment: I ended up using the following code and adding the information to a datagrid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the varying number of spaces is not because the columns are empty...

I'd just keep it simple and use the string tools I'm used to, crude but quick for me:

```
    Dim s As String = TextBox1.Text
    s = s.Replace(vbNewLine, "|").Replace(vbCr, "").Replace(vbLf, "")
    s = s.Replace("| ", "|") ' trim leading space
    Dim iLen As Integer = -1
    Do
        iLen = s.Length
        s = s.Replace("  ", " ")
    Loop Until iLen = s.Length
    Dim aLines() As String = s.Split("|")
    Dim aLine() As String
    Dim aHeader() As String = aLines(0).Split(" ")
    ' process header
    For i As Long = 1 To aLines.GetUpperBound(0)
        aLine = aLines(i).Split(" ")
        Stop
        ' process line
    Next
```

TextBox1 contains your sample with the stray? leading #. If the varying spaces are due to empty columns the massaging will be more complex and maybe better accomplished in the inside loop.

Above I just massage the entire string then place the lines into an array and then loop over the lines.

This is the only the first step in the OP.

I've found writing CSV is problematic especially as the consumers sometimes have different ideas on what the spec says. If possible test with the ultimate consuming program.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the following code and adding the information to a datagrid

```
Dim rowvalue As String
Dim streamReader As IO.StreamReader = New IO.StreamReader(FileName)
    While streamReader.Peek() <> -1
    rowvalue = streamReader.ReadLine()
    DataGridView1.Rows.Add(rowvalue.Split(New String() {" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
End While
```

The problem is that it is rather slow and I still need to remove one of the coumns and adding all the other files. I guess it would be easier to store the information some other way? Any ideas?